# THREEJS Outer Glow to Plane Primitive

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, shader, glow

Anyone know how or have an example of a glow on a plane primitive (planemesh? /mesh) in THREEJS? I've googled and found glows for a cube and sphere but these are more like encasing the object/mesh inside another object which has a transparent material, which looks wrong and is not what I need.

The glow effect I am trying to achieve is the same as:
- Flash AS3 GlowFilter
- Photoshop Layer Effects Outer Glow

I found an example of an outline effect using threejs, this is close but the outline would need to be an gradient with an alpha/opacity gradient.

The glow must only affect the edges of the mesh / primitive (plane).

Thanks

D

Comment: Yeah what suggested would be the way to achieve this, gradient texture on a larger plane... , I had this issue a while back.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I'll reply for potential future readers. You can use [OutlinePass](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_outline.html) from three.js examples.

[image: Sample use of OutlinePass postprocessing]